# $Path changes randomly from day to day

Tags: files-and-directories

I use the following code to open my custom code notebook `code.m`:

```
NotebookOpen[$Path[[6]] <> "\\code.m"]
```

But the `$Path` changes randomly from day to day and I do not know why.

Usually `$Path[[6]]` outputs `C:\Users\XY\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications`, i.e. path to where my file `code.m` is stored.

And usually `$Path[[5]]` outputs `C:\\Users\\XY\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Autoload`.

But from day to day it changes and sometimes I have to use `$Path[[5]]` to open my file because the `$Path[[5]]` changed to `C:\Users\XY\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications` and `$Path[[6]]` changed to something else without me doing any changes in Mathematica folders.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Simply don't rely on the order of the paths, and use `NotebookOpen[FindFile["code.m"]]` instead.

Comment: Or `NotebookOpen @ FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "code.m"}]` to be sure what is opened.

Comment: @Domen: But why this happens? With `FindFile` there could be problem if there are several files with the same name in different folders or if it takes too long to search within huge number of folders/files.

Comment: @Kuba: I used the code primarily because it was simple and short, it worked for a while, but then I noticed sometimes it failed and I have to switch `5` with `6` and next day back from `6` to `5`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I don't know but $Path can be modified easily I would not assume anything but that it contains important paths. p.s. you can check yourself what does it contain when the position of the App changes, maybe this will give the clue.

Comment: Is this all one single mathematica session?  Or are you starting mathematica on different days?  I would wager some other piece of software is modifying your path without you realizing it.

Comment: Yes I think it is even happening in one day but maybe I opened and closed Mathematica few times in that day. But it happens without any changes to Windows or Mathematica or installing any other software. But I usually have opened several instances of Mathematica and in each instance several notebooks so maybe this has something to do with it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Randomly this path `"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.0\AddOns\Applications"` is prepended to `$Path` although this path is already in `$Path`. This shifts position of all other paths.

But I have a workaround since from backward the position of all paths is unchanged so I used instead of original code this one:

```
NotebookOpen[$Path[[-15]] <> "\\code.m"]
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question _why_ it changes (it might be due to some paclets or whatever), and the proposed workaround is again a bad practice. Just don't rely on the order of `$Path`, otherwise, you will get into troubles again when some other paclet will _append_ a directory to `$Path`.

Comment: It is a bug... and this is a workaround. which solves my problem.

Comment: This seems like incredibly bad practice in general. For your own private scripts, it doesn't really matter, but it is downright harmful to offer this as a general solution to finding files or inspecting $Path.